# Install pip3 on new Ubuntu Server 22.04 install (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: ubuntu, python, apt, pip

I have just installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS on my RPi, and I cannot for the life of me get `pip3` to install. (It should already be there, no?)

Here's my `/etc/os-releasse`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

Here's my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
## ...
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy main restricted
# ...
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates main restricted
# ...
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy universe
# ...
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates universe
# ...
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy multiverse
# ...
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates multiverse
# ...
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# ...
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
# ...
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
# ...
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
# ...
```

I ran `# apt update` after every change I tried.

I keep running `# apt install python3-pip`, but it fails with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate
```

And even if I run `# python3 -m pip install ansible` it gives me:

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

I have been trying to manually add entries to the apt sources files (e.g. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pip.list`) but I cannot figure out what the correct entry would look like.
Bonus points for anyone who can tell me how to find the repo for a specific package, and how to format that sources line.

Comment: (`/etc/apt/sources.list` shortened because question kept getting denied because "This looks like spam.".)

Comment: Someone with enough Karma feel free to add the tag `ubuntu-22.04` please! :)

Comment: did you solve your issue?